# Adding code to wordpress site on first page load after login

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, filter, hook

I'm writing a wordpress plugin where I need to inject a beacon (HTML image tag) into the page on the first page load after the user logs in - i.e. the page they are redirected to. Subsequent page views of the same or other pages should not include this beacon code.

I've tried several ways to do this.

I've added a function to the wp_login hook. From this function I've tried adding another function to the wp_footer hook to output the content.

```
// in my class constructor
add_action('wp_login', array($this, 'login'));

public function login() {
    add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'add_beacon'));
}
```

This didn't work so I tried setting both hooks up front and setting a global variable to indicate first load. That wasn't picked up by my second function and neither was a constant.

```
// in my class constructor
add_action('wp_login', array($this, 'login'));
add_action('wp_footer', array($this, 'add_beacon'));

public function login() {
    define('FIRST_RUN', true);
}

public function add_beacon() {
    if (defined('FIRST_RUN')) {
        // output beacon
    }
}
```

Both hook functions fire correctly but whenever I try to make the output of content in the second dependent on the first hook function firing I get no output.

Any ideas how I can do this? Perhaps there's some way I can check without using the wp_login hook at all.

Comment: I also tried to use a class property. That didn't work either.

Comment: You are defining a constant, which expires after the code is processed.  To persist, you'll want to use a $_SESSION variable instead.  In login() try: $_SESSION['first_run'] = true; Then in add_beacon() use: if ( isset( $_SESSION['first_run'] ) ) { // output beacon }

Comment: I'm not particularly keen to use the session if I don't have to as the site I'm working on runs on multiple web servers. I could write a DB session handler but that'd add load. I'm not sure of the hook loading order but I'd assumed that wp_login would come before wp_footer. If that's true wouldn't whatever code I run in wp_login have been processed before wordpress hits wp_footer?

Comment: `wp_login` probably fires before WordPress redirects the user to a separate page.  That redirect landing page fires `wp_footer` and since it's run separately from `wp_login`, the variables you've set aren't passed through.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a per session cookie.

The code would be something like:

```
function my_init() { 
  if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {  
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['beacon'])) {  
      //Track user code / add wp_footer action
      setcookie ('beacon' 'tracked'); 
    }
  }
}
add_action('init','my_init');
```

(Code not tested.. hopefully you get the idea).

If you're not happy with the cookie, you could store last page loaded by user in the usermeta table... however, you'd have to make a call as to how long since last page load is  considered a new session.

Comment: I went with this type of approach in the end which worked. I essentially set a cookie in the wp_login hook and then checked for it and cleared in wp_footer as well as outputting the beacon.